# Trying to upload project with Mantaflow to RebusFarm getting error

Tags: rendering, fluid-simulation

So I did this little animation clip with fluid simulation using mantaflow inside of blender 2.82a everything is baked but I'm getting an error when trying to upload to RebusFarm. Was not bak... "Liquid Particle System". So I tried to contact them and they basically told me this:

"a simulation is built up continuously. on the farm the scene is distributed on several rendernodes, therefore every simulation has to be baked or saved with a cache file."

Which I feel like I did unless I'm missing a step somewhere. I can't find any documentation on this so some help would be welcome or even some pointers. I did pack all into .blend file so I'm not sure where to go from there. Keep in mind I have been learning blender for only 2 months now.

Answer (score 0):

They're answer is cut and paste.  Of course it should be baked before uploading, and it sounds like thats what you did.  I would double check if there are other Mantaflow settings that need baking as well.  I know for gas sims there is the initial bake and the "noise" bake is separate.

Also try in the cache section to name your cache and point it to a custom directory instead of just /tmp/

I also use Rebus and I found that in addition to "pack all files" I need to also check "make all paths absolute" (under the same File>External Data drop down)

I'm currently testing a Fire + Smoke sim made in 2.82 on their farm at the moment. I'll see if it renders.

Comment: Hey thanks I hadn't seen your response I will definitely try it. How did your render go?